# cannot find package "http/template" in GoLang

Tags: glide-golang

While using the http template i encountered with below error:

> TMLTemplate.go:4:3: cannot find package "http/template" in any of:
>           c:\go\src\http\template (from $GOROOT)
>           C:\Users\username\go\src\http\template (from $GOPATH)

Although I have already code to use the HTTP template.
Can anyone guide me on why this error is occurring in the setup?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. We can't verify what you're saying. We need to see the _minimal_ code necessary to demonstrate the problem in the question itself. Without that you're asking us to guess what you wrote and explain the cause, but that's off-topic. We need you to help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

It should be  `html/template`, not `http`.